# Is it possible to define a global configuration variable (custom variable) for my index?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a `product` table in MySQL. I also use Elasticsearch to search products.

I use [this method](https://qafoo.com/blog/086_how_to_synchronize_a_database_with_elastic_search.html) to update Elasticsearch from the `product` table.

Here is a summary of the above artcile to explain how I synchronize Elasticsearch from MySQL :

- I have a table called: `elasticsearch_tracker`
- Every time a row is changed in `product` table, I add a record to `elasticsearch_tracker`
- `elasticsearch_tracker` tells me the latest update which is written to Elasticsearch
- once every 10 seconds I read `elasticsearch_tracker`, and if there are any rows here I send them to Elasticsearch
- Each `product` in Elasticsearch has a `tracker_id`, so I can tell what is the latest update written to Elasticsearch

### Question

In order to get the latest `tracker_id` from elasticsearch, I have to run a query to get the max `tracker_id` among all the documents. This seems to involve a lot of unnecessary processing, as I am only interested in the max `tracker_id`

So I am wondering if it is possible to define a global variable (config varible) for my index and call it `max_tracket_id`. Now instead if adding `tracker_id` once per document and going through the process of finding out its max value, I can just read the value of `max_tracket_id`... obviously I have to update `max_tracket_id` everytime I do a sync from MySQL to Elasticsearch.

Is it possible to define such a global configuration variable per index in Elasticsearch? I am using ES version 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely store `max_tracker_id` in the [index metadata](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-meta-field.html) which is a good place for that.

```
PUT product/_mapping
{
  "_meta": { 
    "max_tracker_id": "12345"
  }
}
```

To retrieve it you can simply run the following command:

```
GET product?filter_path=**._meta
```